# R ubuntu xlsx package

Tags: r, excel, ubuntu, xlsx

I am trying to install xlsx package on Ubuntu in R in order to use a function allowing to insert links in R and then export them to Excel.
Having said that, I simply can't install the package. 
Apparently it has to do wit rJava but I can't figure out a solution.
Any hint?
Here's the message I receive:

```
 Error : .onLoad failed in loadNamespace() for 'rJava', details:
 call: dyn.load(file, DLLpath = DLLpath, ...)
 error: unable to load shared object '/usr/lib/R/site-library/rJava    /libs/rJava.so':
 libjvm.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
 Error : package ‘rJava’ could not be loaded
 ERROR: lazy loading failed for package ‘xlsx’
* removing ‘/home/.../x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/3.2/xlsx’
 Warning in install.packages :
 installation of package ‘xlsx’ had non-zero exit status

 The downloaded source packages are in
  ‘/tmp/RtmpsjilCH/downloaded_packages’
```

Comment: Install package `Rjava`.

Comment: rJava doesn't install either.

Comment: try... `sudo apt-get install r-cran-rjava`

Answer (score 2):

I'm reluctant to install Java on my own machine, but you could try installing a Java runtime environment:

```
sudo apt install default-jre
```

before trying again (perhaps starting by manually install `rJava` as @Bhas suggests).

Instead of a java-based solution though, why not try [`readxl`](https://cran.r-project.org/package=readxl) which has no external dependencies:

```
install.packages("readxl")
```

Answer (score 1):

(I would post this in a comment but I do not have enough reputation)

I agree with @Phil 's advice, but I'd add a small note: `readxl` is from the tidyverse family and has no external dependencies, but it is not able to export data in .xls/.xlsx format. Nevertheless, readxl's own webpage [suggests other dependency-free packages to export data into Excel format](https://readxl.tidyverse.org/#other-relevant-packages), like for example [openxlsx](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/openxlsx/index.html). You might want to check that out.

Still, perhaps you could try to set `dependencies = TRUE` in the `install.packages()` command.

Answer (score 1):

In my experience you have to install java 11

```
sudo apt install default-jre
sudo apt install default-jdk
```

If `java -version` does not point to 11, use:

```
sudo ln -s /usr/lib/jvm/java-11-openjdk-amd64/bin/java /usr/bin/java
```

Then,

```
sudo R CMD javareconf
```

In R:

```
install.packages("rJava")
```